# PDF: Javascript to fill form field

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF document that is essentially a form which gets emailed. I'm trying to add functionality to a button. I want that button to run a Javascript which would fill in the formfield "Notes" with predetermined text *and* with the value of certain form fields.

ie, I click the button and it adds the following to formfield "Notes":
"Blah blah blah (*contents of formfield called "name"*). Blah blah. etc..."

I want the form and that field to still be editable and not flattened at that point.

It seems so simple but I can't find anything on it?

If I could accomplish that, I also would like it to insert more detailed text:

- If FormField "A" is Yes, insert text to formfield notes "blah blah blah"
- If FormField "A" is No, insert text to formfield notes "yada yada yah"

**Update**

- All end users are utilizing Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.
- Since posting I was able to get it to insert text, now I just want to get it to insert text conditionally. If A is yes, then insert X. If A is no, then insert Y, etc... But I have no idea how to do that.

```js
this.getField("Agriculture Operation Notes").value = "Permission to conduct the On-Site Supercheck was granted by the proposed insured, " + this.getField("First Name").value + " " + this.getField("Last Name").value + ", on a " + this.getField("Inspection Type").value + " basis. \n\n\It was so cold outside. \n\n\This is just a demonstration of how we can use JavaScript to improve our reports.\n\n\";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and snippet your code.

Comment: You can add JavaScript to accomplish this but it will only run in a few of the current PDF viewers. What environments do you need this to work in?

Comment: Habib and joelgeraci thanks for your responses.
  - All end users utilize Adobe Acrobat Pro DC to get JavaScript to work
  - I'll edit my original post to include code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work:

```
this.getField("Field To Fill").value = ""+PARA_INTRO+" \n\n"+PARA_OPERATION+"";
```

Then I'm using switch functions to set variable like PARA_INTRO based on the values of other variables.